# IntelliJ and Console Output Colors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to do Java development.  I'm attempting to get my dev environment set up and have run across an interesting issue.  I am setting up my own ConsoleHandler to be used by the Java.util.logging framework.  The base ConsoleHandler prints to System.err for all Log Levels, and this drives me crazy.  In the IntelliJ environment under

```
Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Colors
```

there is a box.  In this box we see the following:

```
Console Standard Output
Console Error Output
.
.
.
Log Console Error
Log Console Warning
```

Clearly "Console Standard Output" refers to System.out and "Console Error Output" refers to System.err.  But how do I print something that would fall under "Log Console Error" and "Log Console Warning".

Please do not post work arounds...  I have all the console output colors I need, this is more intellectual curiosity.

Comment: Would [Grep Console](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=idea) help? or Does it count as *work around*?

Comment: Umm, I really just wanted to know what was going on.  I didn't have a desparate need for more color options.  So, that's a work around.  Or rather, it doesn't explain what's going on.  Meo had the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, it is only for [IntelliJ event log](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/event-log.html).